# Can i recover my bitcoin id with my names

Tags: wallet-recovery

Can I use my names to recover my bitcoin ID and account? I want to recover my bitcoin account but I don't remember anything about it.  I want to use my names.

Comment: Which bitcoin ID and account are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about blockchain.com then there is a reminder to send you your ID.
https://login.blockchain.com/#/reminder